# How to get from angular velocity to acquired phase for neutrino oscillations in matter?

Tags: neutrinos, angular-velocity, eigenvalue

I am reading [Akhmedovs 2000 paper on parametric resonance](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=neutrino%20eigenenergies&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD4QFjAD&url=http://www.ias.ac.in/pramana/jan2000/p5.pdf&ei=geJGUYTXJIeRtQbbh4DIAg&usg=AFQjCNGQJ6-3Qa0rNy05fb2RtRYT2LbDBw&bvm=bv.43828540,d.Yms), and I cannot figure out the math of this particular passage:

> The difference of the neutrino eigenenergies in a matter of density $N_i$ is $2\omega_i$, so that the oscillations phases aquired over the intervals $T_1$ and $T_2$ are
>
> $2\phi_1=2\omega_1T_1$,        $2\phi_2=2\omega_2T_2$

My question here is: What is the relevant formula that links eigenenergy to phase? And angular velocity to eigenenergy?

Comment: How familiar are you with the mathematics of neutrino oscillations in the first place? Do you understand how it all works in free space?

Comment: Some of the basic math of vacuum oscillation is reproduced in [my answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/2954/520) to *"[How can neutrinos oscillate though the lepton flavors have differing masses?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2949/520)"*.